# Fow how long will the Chiranjivis live?

Tags: chiranjivi

There are few Cheeranjivisin the world namely - Parshuram , Krishna Dwayapan Ved Vyas , Aswathama , Kripacharya etc.

For how long will they live ?

Will they live for [1 Kalpa or 100 Brahma Years](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Kalpa-Manvantara-and-Yuga-in-Hindu-mythology/answer/Sumit-Shrivastava-6)

Are they immoral , will they never die ?